# How to execute python scripts from react-js?

Tags: python, reactjs, jupyter-notebook

I have a use case where I need to execute a local python script from the browser and display the output returned.

I have written my web app using react-js.

My current solution is to launch a local instance of a jupyter notebook (assuming the client is already running it) and make the user execute the prefilled first cell, but I want to be able to do this directly from the browser.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

web pages cannot run arbitrary OS commands (such as executing a python scripts) from the browser - due to security reasons

a server has to provide an API for the web page to call (note that Jupyter Notebook is using it's own server to execute commands specified in a browser - python code is NOT executed directly in the browser)

there are many ways how to start a python web server, I personally recommend Flask: http://flask.pocoo.org/

---

*Update 2022:* there is now a project to run Python in the browser, [PyScript](https://pyscript.net/), which might be worth checking for some of the use cases

Comment: I do not want to use a python web server primarily because I need to execute the script as the client user.
Is it not possible to get a socket connection between the ipython kernel and the browser?

Comment: you can use the jupyter's server for sure... if you open Dev Tools > Network tab in your browser with the Notebook, and observe what request is sent when you execute the cell you want to simulate, then you can make the same request from Javascript (e.g. [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/fetch) inside `componentDidMount`)... (note that you might need to provide some security token or other info in headers)

Comment: I will not be able to see the requests in dev tools since its a web socket call. Will have to do something else. Thanks!

Comment: You can see socket requests in dev tools.
Open network tab -> under sub tabs(All, XHR, CSS and so on) choose WS. Here you can see all socket requests with detailed info about the same

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to program in Python but have the code execute in browser, you need either:

A) to run some  kind of python program on client machine (separate from  browser) which would listen and allow browser to connect to it using some kind of Api (Rest etc);

Or B) transpile your Python to client side Javascript which you inject into the  web page client views. There are several tools that support it, such as https://www.transcrypt.org or http://pyjs.org

Or C) use libraries which allow client side Python in browser, such as http://www.skulpt.org (basically similar to B) but does it transparently)